# snapshot table in dbt does not have metadata fields

Tags: snowflake-schema, dbt

I am trying to create a snapshot of a table using dbt. When I create a snapshot, table is created but there are not metadata fields like dbt_valid_to, dbt_valid_from, dbt_scd_id

Here is the code I am trying

```
`{% snapshot test_snp %}`
`{{`
  `config(`
   `materialized = 'table',`
   `target_database = 'tgt_db',`
   `target_schema = 'tgt_schema',`
   `strategy = 'check'`
   `check_cols = 'all'`
   `unique_key='unique_id,`
  `)`
`}}`

`select * from source`

`{% endsnapshot %}`
```

When I don't give materialized = table option, it throws an error "snapshot target is not a snapshot table (missing "dbt_scd_id", "dbt_valid_from", "dbt_valid"to")

Does anyone face the same issue? Thank you for your help

Comment: What happens if you `drop table tgt_db.tgt_schema.test_snp` and try again by running `dbt snapshot`?

Answer (score 0):

`snapshot` is essentially a materialization macro. By setting the config to

```
`materialized = 'table',`
```

you are overriding the snapshot macro's materialization. Just remove this from the config, drop the existing table, and re run `dbt snapshot`. The metadata fields will populate